# Is it possible to use GIT hooks in .git/hooks/ with Atlassian Stash?

Tags: git, githooks, bitbucket-server

Is it possible to use GIT hooks in .git/hooks/ with Stash?

It would like to know if I can write a simple shell/perl script for the post-commit hook to be run by the server on a git push. It should check out a branch to another location.

Answer (score 1):

You should probably have a read of the Stash documentation about repository hooks:

https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/STASH/Using+repository+hooks

This plugin/hook may also be of interest:

https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.ngs.stash.externalhooks.external-hooks